# How to deal a deck of cards?

Tags: c#, arrays, jagged-arrays

I'm trying to create a application to deal a deck of cards. I have already made the deck and also shuffled the deck but I am having trouble dealing it to x number if players 
Here is what I have so far.

```
class Dealer
{
    private string[] suffeledDeck = new string[52];
    private static string[] playerOne = new string[26];
    private static string[] playerTwo = new string[26];
    private static string[] playerThree = new string[26];
    private static string[] playerFour = new string[26];
    private static string[] playerFive = new string[26];
    private static string[] playerSix = new string[26];
    private static string[][] allplayers = new string[][] { playerOne, playerTwo,playerThree,playerFour,playerFive,playerSix };

    private int counter = 0;
    private int playerCount = 6;

    public Dealer(string[] deck)
    { 
        suffeledDeck = deck;
    }

    private void deal()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < suffeledDeck.Length; i++)
        {
            allplayers[counter][0] = suffeledDeck[i];
            counter++;
            if (counter == playerCount)
            {
                counter = 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: it seems your only giving one card to each player always. `allplayers[counter][0] = suffeledDeck[i]` always overwrites the first card that is given up to the last deck

Comment: @X.Li Thanks for improving posts. But please make only substantial edits. At least 3 people need to review your changes before they get approved. That takes time of the reviewers. Make it worth it and leave minor edits to the users having enough rep to edit without needing approval. Thanks.

Comment: @Taifun Thank you for telling me this. I did not know the mechanise behind the editing until I checked the reason why I was banded. I will continue fix minor error once I have enough rep. Thank you all for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one approach, but I would likely use `List<T>`, as Selman22 advises.

```
var sourceIndex = 0;
var handCount = 0;
while (sourceIndex < shuffledDeck.Length)
{
    for (var playerIndex = 0; playerIndex < allplayers.Length; playerIndex++)
    {
        allplayers[playerIndex][handCount] = shuffledDeck[sourceIndex++];
        if (sourceIndex == shuffledDeck.Length)
            break;
    }
    handCount++;
}
```

Example with lists:

```
class Dealer
{
    private List<string> shuffledDeck= new List<string>();
    private static List<string> playerOne = new List<string>();
    private static List<string> playerTwo = new List<string>();
    private static List<string> playerThree = new List<string>();
    private static List<string> playerFour = new List<string>();
    private static List<string> playerFive = new List<string>();
    private static List<string> playerSix = new List<string>();
    private static List<List<string>> allplayers = new List<List<string>> { playerOne, playerTwo,playerThree,playerFour,playerFive,playerSix };

    private int counter = 0;
    private int playerCount = allplayers.Count;
    public Dealer(string[] deck)
    { 
        shuffledDeck= deck;
    }
    private void deal()
    {
        while (shuffledDeck.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (var player in allplayers)
            {
                player.Add(shuffledDeck[shuffledDeck.Length - 1];
                shuffledDeck.RemoveAt(shuffledDeck.Length - 1];
                if (shuffledDeck.Length == 0)
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This approach has the advantage of removing cards that have been dealt from the deck.  Deal from the end because `RemoveAt(0)` copies all of the remaining cards to fill in the gap.

Better initialization, unless you actually need the `playerOne` ... `playerSix` variables:

```
private static int playerCount = 6;
private static List<List<string>> allplayers =
    Enumerable.Range(0, playerCount).Select(i => new List<string());
```

Comment: Could you give me an example that would us lists ?

Comment: Is there an easy way i can make it so that i can pick between 1-6 players and deal accord to the amount of player selcted

Comment: @user2552211 Sure.  Use the initialization code in the last code example, and set playerCount to some different value between 1 and 6.  If you mean to get the number from the user, then that's a rather different topic as it depends on what kind of application this is (console, web, winforms, wpf, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

Use a `List<string[]>`  instead of `string[][]`

Comment: Don't you mean a `List<string>[]`?

Comment: Don't you mean `List<List<Card>>`?

Comment: Don't you mean a `List<Player>` containing a `List<Card>`?